# How to fetch array data from url in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to fetch data from url in react.

There is data below:

```
{"data":[
{"id":"3",
"type":"blocks",
"attributes":{
    "index":1,
    "data":"The Human Torch",
},
{"id":"4",
"type":"blocks",
"attributes":{
    "index":2,
    "data":"is denied",
},
{"id":"5",
"type":"blocks",
"attributes":{
    "index":3,
    "data":"a bank loan",
}
]}
```

Here is my code:

screen.tsx:

```
function App: React.FunctionComponent = ( ) => {    
  const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState({
    blocks: []
  });

  const getBlockData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch( `${some.url}/blocks` ).then((response) => response.json());
    setBlocks(response);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getBlockData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      { blocks.map((block: BlockType) => (
          <div className="content">
            Id:{block.id} 
            <div>
              Type:{block.type}
              Index:{block.attributes.index}
              Data:{block.attributes.data}
            </div>
          </div>
      ))}
    </div> 
  );
};
```

Block.ts:

```
export interface BlockType {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  attributes: {
    index: string;
    data: string;
  };
}
```

I run code but error issue.

error issue:

TypeScript error in :
Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ blocks: never[]; }'.  TS2339

```
133 |           <div className="app">
```

> 134 |             { blocks.map((block: BlockType) => (
> |                      ^
> 135 |                 
> 136 |                   Id:{block.id}
> 137 |                   
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FUPg.png)
> What is my error and how to solve it?
> Who can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map()` is a function for *arrays*, not *objects*.  And `blocks` is an object:

```
const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState({
  blocks: []
});
```

Either call `.map()` on the array (which is a property on your object):

```
blocks.blocks.map(...)
```

Or change your object to just the array you want it to be:

```
const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState([]);
```

---

**Edit:** The data you're showing also doesn't match your object or array *at all*.  The data you're showing is itself an object with a property on it called `data`, and *that* property is an array.  So even once you correct the error, you're just going to have another error.

Define your object to match the structure you expect:

```
const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState({
  data: []
});
```

And iterate over the array property on the object:

```
blocks.data.map(...)
```

---

Basically:

1. Keep your data structures consistent.
2. Know which of your data structures are objects and which are arrays.

Comment: And I ask a question. Is it right for me to use useEffect funtion?

Comment: @Andrey: If you want this to happen in an "effect" (in React terms) then yes.  For example, the `useEffect` shown in your code will execute this code once when the component is initially loaded, then never again for the life of that instance of the component.